# case, setinterval and listing only selected arrays

Tags: javascript, while-loop, setinterval

I'm trying to make interval function, which will change selected div every 10seconds. When i'm on first page, i want it to show items from first array, when im on second i want array 2, etc. this is what i got so far:

```
var timedFunc = '';
var index= new Array(20)
index[0]="index1";
index[1]="index2.";
..

var indextwo= new Array(20)
indextwo[0]="index1";
indextwo[1]="index2";

var tmp = 0;
function display_index(nameofarray) {
if (tmp < 0) { tmp = nameofarray.length-1; }
if (tmp > nameofarray.length-1) { return false; }
document.getElementById('robot').innerHTML = nameofarray[tmp];
tmp = tmp + 1;
}
function indexInterval(m) {
  switch(m) {
    case 1: timeFunc = setInterval("display_index(index)",1000);
    case 2: timeFunc = setInterval("display_index(indextwo)",1000);
    case 3: timeFunc = setInterval("display_index(indexthree)",1000);
    case 4: timeFunc = setInterval("display_index(indexfour)",1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Without discussing your implementation, please describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did in the first paragraph. On the main page, i want to display items(text) from first array every 10 seconds, on the other page(for example registration page) i want it to show items from other array(registration tips) and the implementation: body(onLoad="searchInterval()")
 #cloud
  div.robot(id="robot")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through an array on an interval timer, you can pass the desired array to a function and then use that function to cycle through the array on an interval timer like this:

```
var index0 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
var index1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

function startMyInterval(array) {
    var index = 0;
    var item = document.getElementById('robot');
    setInterval(function() {
        // if we reached the end of the array, start back at beginning
        if (index >= array.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        item.innerHTML = array[index]; 
        ++index;
    }, 10000);
}

// figure out which array of text values you want to use
// for this particular page index0 or index1
// and pass that array to startMyInterval()
startMyInterval(x);
```

This type of implementation avoids the `switch` statement and avoids passing text to `setInterval()`.  It also uses a function closure to keep track of the state that the `setInterval()` callback needs.

Comment: +1 for the good work. Just a comment to user1427907 about the arrays, usually pages that are going to display messages should define the array within those pages instead of defining all messages in different arrays. And about your code, maybe is better to check the existence of the array into the `startMyInterval` function.

Comment: @Fong-WanChau - The OP can add whatever error checking seems appropriate to their situation.  If no array is passed to the function, it will throw an exception which seems appropriate as the function is not being used appropriately, but obviously anyone using this code can provide whatever argument checking their needs require.

Comment: @user1427907 - as you are new to StackOverflow, do you realize that if you receive an answer that answers your question, you are supposed to click the checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to other readers that this answer was the best answer and that your question is now answered?  That also rewards those who provided the answer with some reputation points and you will receive some points yourself for following the procedure.